# Example Code Works as Activity but not as Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm fairly new to Android development. I'm still learning and getting along with example codes i can find online.

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get this example code to work in a fragment Activity, however it works seamlessly as an Activity. I don't know what i'm missing.

Eclipse keeps Highlighting unusual parts of the code, making it difficult to debug

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'll post both working code and one with errors :errors will be **Bold text**

//Working code

```
            package com.example.androidhive;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
            import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;

            public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

                // Progress Dialog
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                EditText inputName;
                EditText inputPrice;
                EditText inputDesc;

                // url to create new product
                private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php";

                // JSON Node names
                private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

                @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

                    // Edit Text
                    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                    // Create button
                    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

                    // button click event
                    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // creating new product in background thread
                            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                        }
                    });
                }

                /**
                 * Background Async Task to Create new product
                 * */
                class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                    /**
                     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                     * */
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Creating product
                     * */
                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
                        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

                        // getting JSON Object
                        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                                "POST", params);

                        // check log cat fro response
                        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                        // check for success tag
                        try {
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully created product
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                                // closing this screen
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                // failed to create product
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    /**
                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                     * **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        // dismiss the dialog once done
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            }
```

// Non Working Code, after turning it into a fragment

```
            package com.example.androidhive;

            import android.app.Fragment;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
            import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;


            public class AddProductsFragment extends **Fragment** {

                public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 0;

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_product,
                            container, false);

                    return rootView;
                }

                // Progress Dialog
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                EditText inputName;
                EditText inputPrice;
                EditText inputDesc;

                // url to create new product
                private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php";

                // JSON Node names
                private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    **setContentView**(R.layout.add_product);

                    // Edit Text
                    inputName = (EditText) **findViewById**(R.id.inputName);
                    inputPrice = (EditText) **findViewById**(R.id.inputPrice);
                    inputDesc = (EditText) **findViewById**(R.id.inputDesc);

                    // Create button
                    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) **findViewById**(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

                    // button click event
                    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // creating new product in background thread
                            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                        }
                    });
                }

                /**
                 * Background Async Task to Create new product
                 * */
                class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                    /**
                     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                     * */
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(**AddProductFragment**.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Creating product
                     * */
                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
                        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

                        // getting JSON Object
                        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                                "POST", params);

                        // check log cat fro response
                        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                        // check for success tag
                        try {
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully created product
                                Intent i = new Intent(**getApplicationContext**(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                                // closing this screen
                                **finish**();
                            } else {
                                // failed to create product
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    /**
                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                     * **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        // dismiss the dialog once done
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            }
```

// I might be failing to import some assets, thing is i don't know where to start in correcting this.

Thanks again for your time and help.

kind Regards
Edem

Comment: You should learn about Fragment first: developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fragments, you should get the reference to your visual elements in `onCreateView()` method, for example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_product, container, false);
    inputName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    return view;
}
```

If you want to use `findViewById()` after `onCreateView()` as already been called (later in the fragment's lifecycle), you can use `getView()` method:

```
inputName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.inputName);
```

Comment: Many Thanks!!! @Szymon it clarified that bit of Code, In writing the background Async Task, do i need to Override the new ProgressDialog(AddProductFragment.this); differently. still getting errors in creating and calling new methods. Thanks again for the help.